# Unable to see the dag that I created programmatically

Tags: airflow

I am trying to create a dag programmatically, using the instructions here: http://airflow.apache.org/faq.html#how-can-i-create-dags-dynamically

While the code runs and does not throw any errors, I am still unable to find the newly created dags.

Comment: Can you please provide code snippet you used while following instructions? It will help to resolve isuue faster

Comment: Hi @ankita, can you add your DAG code, please?